# Efficiency of memory stats using .Q.w in kdb

Tags: kdb

In order to get the memory stats we use .Q.w[] in kdb.
The output of .Q.w is like

```
q).Q.w[]
used| 260928
heap| 67108864
peak| 67108864
wmax| 0
mmap| 0
mphy| 270267293696
syms| 1287
symw| 57285
```

I have written my similar dictionary which provide same output as .Q.w

```
q)`used`heap`peak`wmax`mmap`mphy`syms`symw!(value["\\w"], value ["\\w 2"])
```

On testing, I can see that my dictionary is running faster than .Q.w[]
Few samples:

```
    q)\t:100000 .Q.w[]
    44
    q)\t:100000 `used`heap`peak`wmax`mmap`mphy`syms`symw!(value["\\w"], value ["\\w 2"])
    42
    q)\t:1000000 .Q.w[]
    451
    q)\t:1000000 `used`heap`peak`wmax`mmap`mphy`syms`symw!(value["\\w"], value ["\\w 2"])
    407
    q)\t:1500000 .Q.w[]
    662
    q)\t:1500000 `used`heap`peak`wmax`mmap`mphy`syms`symw!(value["\\w"], value ["\\w 2"])
    613
    q)\t:2000000 .Q.w[]
    860
    q)\t:2000000 `used`heap`peak`wmax`mmap`mphy`syms`symw!(value["\\w"], value ["\\w 2"])
    813
    q)\t:2500000 `used`heap`peak`wmax`mmap`mphy`syms`symw!(value["\\w"], value ["\\w 2"])
    999
    q)\t:2500000 .Q.w[]
    1071
```

My question is, is it more efficient to use value function other than .(dot operator) which is used in .Q.w function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given how small the differences are I suspect this could just be the overhead of running a lambda/function versus not running a lambda/function

```
q)\t:2500000 1+1
129
q)\t:2500000 {1+1}[]
165
```

Also - I'm not sure that `value["\\w 2"]` is doing what you think it's doing. To replicate `.Q.w` you should pass `0` or `1` ..... passing `2` is an attempt to resize the workplace limit to 2mb

Comment: it was an overhead because of lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Terry was correct that it's just the overhead of the lambda. I just want to address this part of the question,

> is it more efficient to use value function other than .(dot operator)
>   which is used in .Q.w function?

The `value`/`get` and the dot operator in the `.Q.w` definition are *essentially* the same thing.

```
q)get
.:
q)value
.:
```

Here we can ignore the trailing colon for the definition of `get` and `value`. We can check that this is a fact by wrapping these definitions in parenthesis to get the `k` functionality, or dropping into the `k` language

```
q)(.)"\\w"
343584 67108864 67108864 0 0 17054650368
q)(.:)"\\w"
343584 67108864 67108864 0 0 17054650368
q)\
  ."\\w"
343584 67108864 67108864 0 0 17054650368
```

In fact... we can add as many as we want! The parser will break it down to a single one anyway

```
q)(.::)"\\w"
343584 67108864 67108864 0 0 17054650368
q)(.:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::)"\\w"
343616 67108864 67108864 0 0 17054650368
q)parse ".:::"
.:
```

From memory, the use of the colon after the `.` is forcing the overloaded `.` to act in its monadic form. x